# Expanding a mySQL table using only mySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a mySQL table whose structure is like this:

```
mysql> select * from things_with_stuff;
+----+---------+----------+
| id | counter | quantity |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |     101 |        1 |
|  2 |     102 |        2 |
|  3 |     103 |        3 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

My goal is to "expand" the table so I end up with something like:

```
mysql> select * from stuff;
+----+---------+
| id | counter |
+----+---------+
|  1 |     101 |
|  2 |     102 |
|  3 |     102 |
|  4 |     103 |
|  5 |     103 |
|  6 |     103 |
+----+---------+
```

And I want to do this "expansion" using only mysql.  Note that I end up with a row per quantity and per counter. Any suggestions?  A stored procedure is not an option here (I know they offer while loops).

Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to comment on [marcos'](http://stackoverflow.com/users/925801/marcos) answer above, but I am on a karma diet. Your large table doesn't have to be as big as the sum of all quantity, it only has to be as big as the largest single quantity - viz. 3 in this example (as opposed to 6 if it had to be the full sum). I still think it would be valuable to have a way to generate that table (or the rows) on the fly. OP: why are stored procedures not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do the trick as long as `some_large_table` has a length greater than or equal to the largest `quantity` in `things_with_stuff`. For example, let `some_large_table` be a big fact table in a data warehouse.

```
SELECT @kn:=@kn+1 AS id, counter
FROM (SELECT @kn:=0) k, things_with_stuff ts
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS num
    FROM (SELECT @rn:=0) t, some_large_table
    ) nums ON num <= ts.quantity;
```

Comment: Btw, wrap the query in a CREATE TABLE stuff ( ... ); statement as needed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a maximum value for `quantity`, you could do:

```
INSERT INTO things SELECT counter FROM things_with_stuff WHERE quantity > 0;
INSERT INTO things SELECT counter FROM things_with_stuff WHERE quantity > 1;
INSERT INTO things SELECT counter FROM things_with_stuff WHERE quantity > 2;
--... and so on until the max.
```

It's a bit of a hack but it should do the job.

If the ordering is important you could do a clean up afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes in databases a table named `num` (number) with a single column `i`, filled with all integers from 1 to 1000000. It's not hard to make such a table and populate it.

Then you could use this if `stuff.id` is auto incremented:

```
INSERT INTO stuff
( counter )
    SELECT ts.counter
    FROM things_with_stuff AS ts
      JOIN num
        ON num.i <= ts.quantity
```

Comment: Wait, what? You can do `JOIN ON a <= b`? Is this normal SQL or just some MySQL-special thing?

Comment: @Alexandr: I think all decent RDBMS allow that. Besides (not so decent) MySQL.

Comment: That's awesome. I think my mind just exploded with stuff I could do with this. Then it hit he, by the time I have use for any of it, I've forgotten xD.

Comment: See ***`(theta) θ-join`***: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#.CE.B8-join_and_equijoin

Comment: If we can come up with sql to generate that list of integers to use as an inner select rather than needing to precompute num, I think this might just work!